# Error in MATLAB: Input argument is undefined

Tags: matlab, variables, undefined, exists

I'm developing an app for my school diploma project.

The variable exists but the error is:

> ??? Input argument "esn" is undefined.

Here is the code:

```
trained_esn = esn;
switch trained_esn.learningMode
case 'offline_singleTimeSeries'
    % trainInput and trainOutput each represent a single time series in
    % an array of size sequenceLength x sequenceDimension
    if strcmp(trained_esn.type, 'twi_esn')
        if size(trainInput,2) > 1
            trained_esn.avDist = ...
                mean(sqrt(sum(((trainInput(2:end,:) - trainInput(1:end - 1,:))').^2)));
        else
            trained_esn.avDist = mean(abs(trainInput(2:end,:) - trainInput(1:end - 1,:)));
        end
    end
```

where esn is defined :

```
esn = generate_esn(nInputUnits, nInternalUnits, nOutputUnits, ...
'spectralRadius',0.8,...
'inputScaling', ...
[0.1;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;
0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2], ...
'inputShift', [0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0], ...
'teacherScaling',0.3,'teacherShift',-0.2,
'feedbackScaling', 0, 'type', 'plain_esn');

esn.internalWeights = esn.spectralRadius * esn.internalWeights_UnitSR;
```

Comment: It would help if you showed us where you define `esn`.

Comment: alright one second

Comment: esn = generate_esn(nInputUnits, nInternalUnits, nOutputUnits, ...
  'spectralRadius',0.8,...
  'inputScaling',[0.1;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2;0.2],...
  'inputShift',[0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0], ...
  'teacherScaling',0.3,'teacherShift',-0.2,'feedbackScaling', 0, 'type', 'plain_esn'); 

esn.internalWeights = esn.spectralRadius * esn.internalWeights_UnitSR;

Comment: pleaaase help meeee :'(

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what `generate_esn` is supposed to do, what it returns, or if it even completes successfully in your code. The error you're getting seems pretty clear, so I would set a break point after `esn` is supposed to be defined and before it is used and check that the value is actually what you expect.

Comment: can i send you the whole code ? probably you'll get where the problem is and help me with it pleaaase :/